# Selenium Switch the view to another window/tab

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to switch the view back to a previously opened Window/Tab
I tried:

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(ChromeDriver.WindowHandles[0]);
```

It is switching the Driver back, but without making it the one that is currently displayed, I know that because the driver is performing actions on it successfully after I switch to it.

What I need is:

let us say I opened google.com in a tab then opened yahoo.com in another tab and the display is now on yahoo.com

[image: Selenium switch view first tab]

now how to make it like this:

[image: Selenium switch view second tab]
I am using  ChromeDriver;

Comment: what you mean here "but without making it the one that is currently displayed" can u pls explaiin ? It is not clear.

Comment: Guess u have to do driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.ALT + Keys.NUMPAD1)

Comment: did not work, I tried other keyboard combination,(ctrl+tab) not working too

Comment: Use action class >> Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();

Comment: Why do you need it to switch to it visibly?

Comment: to be sure that it is happening the right way